# asp.net mvc cache remove outputcache in entire website

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using the standard outputcache tag in my MVC app. i have this

```
   [OutputCache( Duration =600, VaryByParam = "none", Location = OutputCacheLocation.Server)]
```

the thing is that i want to force the removal of entire collection of cache from my website with the single click of the button in asp.net mvc. how can i do that? i have tried many examples in the stackoverflow site unsuccessfully.

2) where can i find the collection of outputcache in asp.net mvc c#.

Comment: I'm not sure if MVC uses this, but in .NET 4.0, you can build a custom output cache provider; therefore, you can control where the cache is stored and remove it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg650661.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/914c7ktw.aspx) method to remove the cached output of the given page by providing the url that was used to serve the cached action.

Comment: ok so this is not possible by any means Response.RemoveOutputCacheItem("/")?

Comment: @mazharkaunainbaig, no, it is not possible.